# how to show telugu or some other language (non-English)words with english keyboard in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, translation, android-softkeyboard, google-translate

I want to create a app which is need to show the text in local language with custom keyboard for ex: if I type hello that should be show as హలో is there any api or libraries?

Comment: "some other language" is quite broad specification. I assume you mean to say "non-latin alphabet"?

Comment: The user usually choses what the keyboard shows and your app is free to show text in any language but probably automated based on the device localization settings as well https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization - entering "hello" and showing the same word in a different language would require a translation service (e.g. https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing )

Comment: if I use cloud transaltion is it work in offiline also?